# Интерфейс и потоки QT

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Верно ли то, что все окна и виджеты находяться в одном потоке? Т.е. при блокировке одного окна, заблокируются все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, ui поток нельзя блокировать. Но, мы можем выполнять события пользовательского интерфейса в произвольном месте... Более подробно об этом можно узнать [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    while(true) {
        qInfo() << "Do something";
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```